# Installing Ubuntu on my new Laptop for Dual Boot alongside Win 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a new Lenovo G50-80 laptop with the following specs.

Ci5 5200/ 4GB / 1TB / 2GB Graph / Win 10 64-bit pre-installed

[image: current partitions]

[image: Partition manager 1.]

[image: Partition manager 2.]

It has Secure Boot enabled and also Secure Boot on.

[image: Secure Boot / UEFI Info]

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Win 10 and make it a dual boot system. I started by making a USB for Ubuntu and booted using the USB. I choose **Something Else** in installation type.

I will make partitions as below.

```
Swap 8 GB
/root 50 GB (ext4)
/home 50 GB (ext4)
```

But I did not know where to place the bootloader from the menu that is available. **Should I place it in the UEFI partition**? If I do so will it not affect my Win 10?

[image: Bootloader Option]

I need to use GRUB as my bootloader and I don't want to use the Windows bootloader.

Should I disable SECURE BOOT?

Comment: There is already a detailed guide about all the issues regarding dual boot [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi). Go through that. And yes, disable secure boot.

Comment: where to place the Bootloader from the menu that is available ? 
Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need to disable secure boot. Just make sure to **boot your Ubuntu installation media in EFI** mode. Then set mount points for the root, home and swap.

Keep `/dev/sda` for the bootloader installation as it is. Ubuntu installer (grub btw) is smart enough to detect your EFI, and non-Linux partitions.

Your swap space is too large though.

Answer (score -1):

Install the bootloader in `/dev/sda` as it is the main partition.

Also, you need to disable the secure boot in order to install Ubuntu.